# Flutter - how do you update the value of textfield without reopening the widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple TextFormField, all have their own value from a file.
My problem:
-when I change the value of the TextFormField, it changes the value of it's own parameter, but it only changes the other TextFormField(based on the same parameter) when I reopen that page.
I tried use setState, but I don't know what parameter should it have.
How should I use setState / what would be a better option?
This is how I change the values:

```dart
onChanged: (value) => 
       { class.data.minimum = int.parse(value), 
           setState(() {
              class.data.minimum=int.parse(value);
               })
           },
```

Comment: can you share full widget?

Comment: this widget is only a container with a text and the textformfield, that's why I didn't add it

Comment: did you try providing `key` on textField?

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: on TextField there is an `key:`

Comment: yes, but what kind of key?

Comment: as for text you can use `ValueKey`,  but in your case use `globalKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default for text you can use `ValueKey`, but in your case use `globalKey`